# this.data is null - Facebook Comments

Tags: facebook, comments, firebug

I have this code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
     appId  : '167549853323291',
     status : true, // check login status
     cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
     xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
  });
};
</script>
<fb:comments href="http://auto.receptie.ro/test.html"></fb:comments>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the link: http://auto.receptie.ro/test.html

When I click in the input box, firebug return error:

```
this.data is null
http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yA/r/HG9KOfvPTU4.js
Line 59
```

Then I click out and click again in the input box, firebug return error:

```
this._input is undefined
http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yA/r/HG9KOfvPTU4.js
Line 56
```

Comment: I get no such error and am able to post comments on your test page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to request XFBML parsing twice; this can cause errors.

Try removing `#xfbml=1` from the Facebook JavaScript SDK source URL. It conflicts with the `xfbml: true` in `FB.init()`.